# Fontawesome showing question mark instead of icon

Tags: swift, font-awesome

Code:

```
btn?.setTitle("\u{f2ed}", for: .normal).
```

I created a new project with a button and created IB conncetion for it.I added fontawesome-webfont.ttf to my project and info.plist as well.when i run the project getting question mark instead of actual icon.any help will be appreicated.thanks in advance

Comment: Did you set the custom font in buton?

Comment: no.how to do that?

Comment: in the interface builder -- > select your button -- > Attributes Inspector --> Font -- > click on T then select Font to custom on next select Font Awesome Family

Comment: The highest code in `fontawesome-webfont.ttf` is `f18b`

Comment: @vadian Sir, https://fontawesome.com/icons/trash-alt?style=solid

Comment: @SahilManchanda The solid font is not the webfont.

Answer (score 0):

Your code and output is working well (but it is not clear what is your question and expectation).

Here is another example:

```
let iconUniChar: UniChar = 97
let someString = String(format: "%C", iconUniChar)
```

The value for `someString` will be

```
a
```

This has to do with how characters are represented using ASCII. 
(a is 97, b is 98, c is 99 ....)

In your example you are assigning a `hexadecimal` while in my example the value is a decimal one.

If you check an online hex to char converter [(like this one)](http://string-functions.com/hex-string.aspx) you will see that the conversion fails as well.

Comment: btn?.setTitle("\u{f2ed}", for: .normal). i checked this format as well. getting same question mark

Comment: The question mark represents some kind of error but instead of crashing it notifies you of the misuse. In this case you have no representation for what you are trying. So what are you actually trying?

Comment: why not just btn?.setTitle("my title", for: .normal)

Answer (score 0):

Via Interface Builder

[image]

Via code

```
btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Font Awesome 5 Free", size: 17)
```

Answer (score 0):

in info.plist FontAwesome.otf is added to the fonts provided by the application .

[image]